# how to format text in php (part 2)

Tags: php

I am trying to customise a woocommerce email using php. I want it to look like:

> We’re delighted to let you know that the first print of *The Versatile Home* is now available and we are able to fulfil your pre-order. Your invoice is below and here's a link to make payment: [click here to pay by credit/debit card or PayPal.](https://paypal.com)

> Alternatively, you can make payment by bank transfer to Sort Code: 00-00-00, Acct #: 00000000, Acct name: xxxxx, quoting order # [can the field be inserted?] as the reference. As soon as we’ve received the payment we’ll get your order off to you straight away.

So far I have done the first part:

```
<?php if ( $order->needs_payment() ) { ?>
    <p>
    <?php
    printf(
        wp_kses(
            /* translators: %1$s Site title, %2$s Order pay link */
            __( 'We’re delighted to let you know that the first print of <i>The Versatile Home</i> is now available and we are able to fulfil your pre-order. Your invoice is below and here is a link to make payment: %2$s', 'woocommerce' ),
            array(
                'a' => array(
                    'href' => array(),
                ),
            )
        ),
        esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ),
        '<a href="' . esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'click here to pay by credit/debit card or PayPal', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>'
    );
    
    ?>
    </p>
```

but I can't work out how to add the next paragraph including a link to the order number.

I also cannot italicise *The Versatile Home* in the first paragraph.

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have now used the yaymail instead which makes life a lot easier!

Comment: Please do not add answers that doesn't answer the original question.